# Why is my recent Envoyer deployment not showing?

Tags: laravel

I just deployed using Envoyer and there were no errors. However, I don't see the new version of the site in my browser.

I SFTP'd into the server, and sure enough the new files are there.

I SSH'd into the `current` directory and ran `php artisan cache:clear` but it didn't make a difference; I still see the old version of the site.

I've done tons of deployments and never encountered this before. How do I fix this?

Comment: is your _browser_ caching the page?

Comment: No. I've used several browsers and a mobile device.

Comment: Sounds like maybe opcache is enabled. Try restarting PHP

Comment: @DerekPollard Please put that in an answer so I can mark it as correct, because that worked! Strange though, because Envoyer is supposed to restart PHP FPM automatically, and I didn't enable OPcache in Forge yet. Weird...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the symptoms you've listed, it sounds like `OPcache` is enabled.

Restart `PHP` with the following command:

```
sudo service phpX.X-fpm reload
```

Where `X.X` is the version of PHP you're using.

Answer (score 2):

Just adding here. I ran into the same issue after changing the PHP version on the site inside of Forge. My server now has multiple versions of PHP on it. I had to go to the site inside of Envoyer, then go to the server, then updated the PHP version to the new PHP version of the site. Now, FPM will reload the proper PHP version.

Answer (score 0):

I was running into this as well, and solved it with the following steps

1. Go to "Servers" tab in Envoyer
2. Click "Update Server" icon
3. Enable "Reload FPM After Deployments"